# What can be said regarding $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$ if ...

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I left the title such as it is due to the abstraction of the question and its length. What follows is the full question : "Let $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ be defined at each point $x_0 \in (a,b)$. We define function $g$, such that $g(x)=f(x)$, except in the set $S$, where the set $S$ has no limit points in the set $(a,b)$. What can be said regarding $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$?"

My work so far : Let $\lim_{x\to x_o} f = L$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} g=M$. If $L$ is defined at each point $x_0 \in (a,b)$, then every point $(a,b)$ is a limit point of $dom(f)$. Also $(a,b)\subset dom(f)$.

$g(x)=f(x) \rightarrow M=L$. Now if $g(x) \neq f(x) \rightarrow M \neq L$ for some $x_0\in (a,b)$.

If $g \neq f$, we have that $dom(g) = S$.

If a function $g$ has a limit on the interval $(a,b)$ at some point $x_0$, then $x_0$ must be a limit point of $(a,b)$.  Since $S$ has no limit points in the  set $(a,b)$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$ is not defined on the interval $(a,b)$. I'm assuming  that $x_0 \in dom(g)$. Is this right?

Comment: Every point of a subset of $(a,b)$ without limit points has to be isolated. Thus WLOG you can assume that $f=g$ except for a single point $x_0$. Thus $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)$.

Comment: I can't really follow your logic, it is very convoluted: you just defined single $L$, it is not "defined at each point". I don't understand the "$g(x)\neq f(x)\to M\neq L$" line. Are you saying that different functions imply different limits? That's just not true. Also being different doesn't imply anything about domains. Btw we know the domain of both $f$ (which is $(a,b)$ or at least some dense subset of) and $g$ (domain of $f$ minus $S$) to begin with. I don't understand any claims about that. The way you jump between domain, limits and limit points looks wrong to me, at least very unclear.

Comment: What I meant to say, is that if two functions are not equal then they cannot always have equal limits on some interval. I now see this is wrong.

Comment: In particular $x_0\in(a, b) $ is not a limit point of $S$ and thus there is a neighborhood $I$ of $x_0$ such that $I\cap S=\emptyset$. Now $f=g$ on $I$ and hence limiting behavior of both $f, g$ at $x_0$ is exactly the same.